# Lack of response from the device through Python Serial library

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I have a device which is configured through an RS-232 port. I want to write my own software in Python which would configure the device through the port. The problem is program writes successfully the bytes to the serial port, but there is no response from the device. The device manual mentions that the device should respond by  characters if a command is correct and by error code if not. But there is no response at all.

Using the Serial Monitor App I looked at how the original software communicates with the device (I looked at all packets), this is why in the code below I added the setting of dtr and rts to zero. It was present in the communication from the original software and not in Python. Did not help.
One difference I see is in HandFlow packet (this is from the **original software**):

```
IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_HANDFLOW: Set handshake information
  ControlHandShake=1
  FlowReplace=64
  XonLimit=2048
  XoffLimit=512
```

This is from **Python**:

```
IOCTL_SERIAL_SET_HANDFLOW: Set handshake information
  ControlHandShake=18
  FlowReplace=64
  XonLimit=2048
  XoffLimit=512
```

The original software is written in Labwindows/CVI (National Instruments) so I assume it is C/C++. It is very annoying to see it works on the same PC on original software and not in Python. Please HELP!

Below, there is my code in **Python**:

```
import serial as ps

ser=ps.Serial('COM5', baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, stopbits=1, write_timeout=0, timeout=0, parity=ps.PARITY_NONE, dsrdtr=True)

print(ser.name)

ser.dtr=0
ser.rts=0
#commands to the device
ser.write(b'INST:NSEL 1\r')
ser.flush()
ser.write(b'*IDN?\r')

#ser.write(b'INST:CNUM?\r')
#ser.write(b'STAT?\r')

#ser.write(b'CONF:CALG 10\r')

print('Done!')

#print(ser.read(10))

ser.close()
print('Done!!')
```

I ruled out some possible causes of the problem:

1. I use the RS-232 - USB converter, it works on the same computer I run the Python program with the original software, therefore the RS-232 - USB converter works correctly;
2. I can see the commands sent to the device from the original software by using a Serial Monitor App and I use in Python the same commands - therefore the serial commands are correct.

Comment: "*program writes successfully the bytes to the serial port, but there is no response*" -- Then you really have no evidence that the writes are successful. Explain in detail what is "*Serial Monitor App*"? Ideally you want to be examining what the target device receives at the target device itself. Your specification of `timeout=0` is not ideal and problematic; instead try `timeout=none`.

Comment: The app was precisely HHD Software Device Monitoring Studio, I monitored data flow through a virtual COM port (Prolific). Thank you very much, setting the timeout to None solved my problem - the device is responsive! I would not think the solution is so trivial. In my defense, I have to mention that on the Pyserial official page (https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/shortintro.html) just in one example timeout is set to None. This practically ends the case, many thanks once more.